# How to get the column for a column having max value in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'p1_c': [1,10,3,40],
                   'p2_c': [4,3,4,14],
                   'p3_c': [5,2,8,78],
                   'p1_v': [776,1776,300,600],
                   'p2_v': [998,98,100,100],
                   'p3_v': [800,80,50,500]
                  })
df
   p1_c  p2_c  p3_c  p1_v  p2_v  p3_v
0     1     4     5   776   998   800
1    10     3     2  1776    98    80
2     3     4     8   300   100    50
3    40    14    78   600   100   500
```

(p1_c,p1_v),(p2_c,p2_v),(p3_c,p3_v) are in groups and describing same thing.
I want the get the v-th column value of the one having the highest c-th value

For example see in row 0  :

```
df[[p1_c,p2_c,p3_c]].max(axis=1)   
#get the max value i.e p3_c
```

So I want p3_v value as an output (i.e 800). Same pattern followed by row 1,2,and 3.

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
   p1_c  p2_c  p3_c  p1_v   p2_v  p3_v  RESULT
 0  1     4     5    776    998    800   800
 1  10    3     2    1776    98    80    1776
 2  3     4     8    300    100    50    50
 3  40   154    78   600    100    500   100
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Sir, is it clear now, what I want as an output now ? @Diptangsu Goswami

Comment: Unfortunately it is not.

Comment: @Amit It's clear to me. He's trying to get corresponding max values i.e. if in row 0 max is at column `p3_c` he wants to get `p3_v` in that row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this with `df.to_records`, that I find simpler, and could be the fastest way:

```
df['RESULT']=[row[list(row).index(max(list(row)[1:4]))+3]for row in df.to_records()]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   p1_c  p2_c  p3_c  p1_v  p2_v  p3_v  RESULT
0     1     4     5   776   998   800     800
1    10     3     2  1776    98    80    1776
2     3     4     8   300   100    50      50
3    40    14    78   600   100   500     500
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with `filter` to get _c and _v columns and use `where` to replace by nan values in _v columns where the value in _c column are not the mask per row. then get the `max`

```
#get only _c columns
dfc = df.filter(regex='_c')

df['RESULT'] = (df.filter(regex='_v') #get _p columns
                  #keep value in _p where max in _c per row 
                  .where(dfc.eq(dfc.max(axis=1).to_numpy()[:, None]).to_numpy())
                  .max(axis=1) #get the max
               )
print (df)
   p1_c  p2_c  p3_c  p1_v  p2_v  p3_v  RESULT
0     1     4     5   776   998   800   800.0
1    10     3     2  1776    98    80  1776.0
2     3     4     8   300   100    50    50.0
3    40   154    78   600   100   500   100.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not an ideal solution but it solves the problem.

```py
from pandas import DataFrame

df = DataFrame({'p1_c': [1,10,3,40], 'p2_c': [4,3,4,14], 'p3_c': [5,2,8,78], 'p1_v': [776, 1776, 300, 600], 'p2_v': [998, 98, 100, 100], 'p3_v': [800, 80, 50, 500]})

df['RESULT'] = [df.loc[i, df.loc[i, df.columns[:3]].idxmax(axis=1)[:-1] + 'v'] for i in range(len(df))]
```

```
   p1_c  p2_c  p3_c  p1_v  p2_v  p3_v  RESULT
0     1     4     5   776   998   800     800
1    10     3     2  1776    98    80    1776
2     3     4     8   300   100    50      50
3    40    14    78   600   100   500     500
```

Answer (score 0):

Use, [`Series.str.endswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html) along with [`DataFrame.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) along `axis=1` to extract the column names which ends with `_c` and containing the max values, then use [`Series.str.rstrip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html) along with `.add` to replace the `_c` with `_v` in those column names, finally use [`DataFrame.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) to get the values from the dataframe based on this `cols`:

```
cols = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.endswith('_c')].idxmax(axis=1)
cols = cols.str.rstrip('_c').add('_v')
df['RESULT'] = df.lookup(df.index, cols)
```

Result:

```
# print(df)

   p1_c  p2_c  p3_c  p1_v  p2_v  p3_v  RESULT
0     1     4     5   776   998   800     800
1    10     3     2  1776    98    80    1776
2     3     4     8   300   100    50      50
3    40   154    78   600   100   500     100
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
data={'p1_c':[1,10,3,40],'p2_c':[4,3,3,14],'p3_c':[5,2,8,78],'p1_v':[776,1776,300,600],'p2_v':[998,98,100,100],'p3_v':[800,80,50,500]}
df_1=pd.DataFrame(data)
list=[]
for i in range(4):
  if df_1[['p1_c','p2_c','p3_c']].max(axis=1)[i]==df_1.loc[i,'p3_c']:
     list.append(df_1.loc[i,'p3_v'])
  else:
     list.append(df_1[['p1_v','p2_v']].max(axis=1)[i])


df_1['Result']=list
df_1
```

output

```
  p1_c  p2_c    p3_c    p1_v    p2_v    p3_v    Result
0         1     4   5   776     998       800     800
1         10    3   2   1776    98        80      1776
2          3    3   8   300     100       50      50
3         40    14  78  600     100       500     500
```